# Is casting of infinity to integer undefined?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is the casting of infinity (represented by float) to an integer an undefined behavior?

The standard says:

> 4.10  Floating-integral conversions
>
> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
>   is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
>   be represented in the destination type.

but I can't tell whether "truncated value cannot be represented" covers infinity.

I'm trying to understand why `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` and `static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() )` have different results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity () << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int> (std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity () ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0  
-2147483648
```

The result of `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` [is well defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) and equal to `0`, but I can't find any information about casting infinity.

Comment: Don't forget that `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` is only useful if `std::numeric_limits<int>::has_infinity == true` and it is not.

Comment: @NathanOliver, you are right, but even if `has_infinity == false` result of `infinity ()` is defined.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value infinity cannot be represented in an `int`.

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion is. `<float>::infinity()` in this context returns a float, then you cast that float to int. This is well defined behavior that is different than `<int>::infinity()` which is also well defined behavior. There is nothing special about this float, if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: @Thebluefish, `returns a float, then you cast that float to int. This is well defined` Where is this defined?

Comment: An integer has a limited range. How would infinity *not* have to be truncated?

Comment: @JesperJuhl - truncation of floating-point values, as the text quoted in the question says, means that the **fractional part** is discarded. That's intended for the more usual case of things like 1.25, which can be converted to 1. If the value is large enough that there is no fractional part, truncation leaves the value unchanged.

Comment: @Glutton, `<T>::infinity()` returns `T`. so `<float>::infinity()` returns a float. You then cast that float to an int via `static_cast<int>`.

Comment: @Thebluefish: That cast is only possible under certain conditions, one of them being that the float value lies within the range of `int`, or close enough that truncation gets it in range.

Comment: @BenVoigt OP is trying to compare two well-defined values, one that he then casts. I'm not sure how that statement relates to that problem. Unless you're implying that float cannot be cast to int, or is otherwise Undefined Behavior?

Comment: I don't see how the conversion can be well defined since an integer cannot represent infinity. The result is probably implementation defined, and in most cases the conversion routine probably falls back to a bit cast.

Comment: @Thebluefish: The entire point of the question is "can you cast an infinity float to int?". You keep saying "of course, just cast the infinity float to int". This doesn't answer anything.

Comment: The value of `<int>::infinity()` isn't meant to mean anything unless `<int>::has_infinity` is `true`.It's a mistake to reason anything at all about it.

Comment: @Thebluefish: I don't need to imply that a cast of `float` to `int` can be Undefined Behavior, the Standard quote right there in the question clearly says that it can be.

Comment: _"The result of std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity() is well defined and equal to 0"_ but it's not infinity :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You said

> I can't tell whether "truncated value cannot be represented" covers infinity

but it all boils down to

> What is the result of truncating infinity.

The C standard (incorporated into C++ via 26.9) answers that quite plainly:

[image: C standard semantics for <code>trunc</code>]

Since truncation of infinity is still infinity, and infinity cannot be represented in `int` (I hope there's no question about this part), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Do we have any evidence that "truncation" in this sense is equivalent to the behaviour of the C library `trunc` function?

Comment: This answer is not fully satisfactory, furthermore it does not cover the case of NaN values.

Comment: @chqrlie: The question did not ask about NaNs

Answer (score 27):

Casting of infinity to integer is undefined.

> The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

Says it all. Since truncation removes precision but not magnitude, a truncated infinity is still infinity and integers cannot represent infinity.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm trying to understand why `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` and `static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() )` have different results.

The standard says: [18.3.2.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.limits.members)

> static constexpr T infinity() noexcept;
>
> 47 Representation of positive infinity, if available. [216]
>
> 48 Meaningful for all specializations for which has_infinity != false. Required in specializations for which is_iec559 != false.

--- edit ---

According to 18.3.2.7/1 [numeric.special]

> 1 All members shall be provided for all specializations. However, many values are only required to be meaningful under certain conditions (for example, epsilon() is only meaningful if is_integer is false). Any value that is not “meaningful” shall be set to 0 or false.

Comment: The specialization for `float` § 18.3.2.7 has `inline static constexpr float infinity() noexcept { return value ; }`

Comment: @BenVoigt That's 18.3.2.7 in mine, will edit accordingly.