# Same code in C that results in different outputs

Tags: c

I have a code that given a matrix, it takes the minimum value in a line and subtracts this value from all values in the same line. Example:

1 4 5

5 7 6

5 8 8

Results in

0 3 4

0 2 1

0 3 3

The logic of the code works in Java but not on C. In C, the code give different results in netbeans and in a online compiler. An another online compiler it appears the error: "*** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated
"

```
int Matrix() {

int a[2][2];
int i, j, lin, col, min;

a[0][0] = 1;
a[0][1] = 4;
a[0][2] = 5;
a[1][0] = 5;
a[1][1] = 7;
a[1][2] = 6;
a[2][0] = 5;
a[2][1] = 8;
a[2][2] = 8;

for (lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {

    min = 10000;
    for (col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        if (a[lin][col] < min)
            min = a[lin][col];
    }
    for (col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        a[lin][col] = a[lin][col] - min;
      }
    }   
  }

int main() {
   Matrix();
}
```

Comment: You're accessing `a[2][2]` but that doesn't exist; valid array indexes on `int a[2][2]` are 0 and 1 only.  I'm not sure how it works in Java, but Java ain't C.  Change the definition of the array to `a[3][3]`.  (And no, C does not, and is not required, to protect you from your own mistakes.  And some compilers will complain.  Use enough warnings that yours does.)

Comment: Surprisingly similar to [Subtracting a value from lines of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574933/subtracting-a-value-from-lines-of-a-matrix)

Comment: Classic "off by one" error.   Indexing of arrays starts from `0` in C, not `1`, so an array with `2` elements has valid indices `0` and `1`.    The same goes for multiple dimensions.  In your code, accessing any `a[i][j]` where `i` or `j` is `2` or more gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get different results with different compilers, that's almost a 100% proof that your code has undefined behavior. (Read about it to find out why it is your worst nightmare.) Turning on compiler warnings is a good way to find the source of undefined behavior.

Compiling this gives loads of warnings.

```
$ compile mat.c 
++ clang -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic-errors mat.c
mat.c:4:5: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
int i, j, lin, col, min;
    ^
mat.c:4:8: warning: unused variable 'j' [-Wunused-variable]
int i, j, lin, col, min;
       ^
mat.c:8:1: warning: array index 2 is past the end of the array (which contains 2
      elements) [-Warray-bounds]
a[0][2] = 5;
^    ~
mat.c:3:1: note: array 'a' declared here
int a[2][2];
^
mat.c:11:1: warning: array index 2 is past the end of the array (which contains
      2 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
a[1][2] = 6;
^    ~
mat.c:3:1: note: array 'a' declared here
int a[2][2];
^
mat.c:14:1: warning: array index 2 is past the end of the array (which contains
      2 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
a[2][2] = 8;
^    ~
mat.c:3:1: note: array 'a' declared here
int a[2][2];
^
mat.c:27:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
6 warnings generated.
```

Change `int a[2][2];` to `int a[3][3];` and then fix the other warnings.

One more thing:

Change `min = 10000` to `min=a[lin][0]` instead, in case the values are higher than 10000.

Comment: I changed to a[3][3] and everything is fixed now.

Comment: @Pinteco Glad to hear it. Always look at compiler warnings when you're debugging. They are there to help.