# roundf() returns different values in debug and release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I was checking why my app behaves differently in release and debug mode. I end up with roundf() function. And here is the smallest test program to illustrate the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
  float step = INFINITY;
  unsigned rh = (unsigned)roundf(step);

  std::cout << rh << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is `0` in Debug Mode and `4294967295` in Release Mode.
I compiled the code for x86 platforms with VS2019 v16.10.2 using ISO C++14 Standard

My question is that whether this is a known behaviour or bug in the compiler? What should we expect according to the standard?

Thank you.

**More tests done for the commenters:**
Below code always returns `inf` as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
  float step = INFINITY;
  float rh = roundf(step);

  std::cout << rh << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And below code always returns `4294967295` no matter you are in debug or release mode (which is expected too).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
  float step = INFINITY;
  unsigned rh = (unsigned)step;

  std::cout << rh << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: fwiw, `roundf` returns `±∞` unmodified, so the question boils down to `float step = INFINITY; unsigned rh = step;` in debug vs release builds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is casting of infinity to integer undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795544/is-casting-of-infinity-to-integer-undefined)

Comment: @Kaznow Please see my last test case, which has no issue.

Comment: @MehmetFide one test case that passes means nothing when your code has undefined behavior. Undefined behavior producing the expected output is the worst incarnation of UB and unfortunately rather common

Comment: The last test case is the same as `unsigned rh = (unsigned)INFINITY;`  (still UB). What value do you expect an `unsigned int` to hold when given `INFINITY` ? Note that `4294967295` is not infinity as there is no concept of infinity for the integers used by computers.

Comment: " no matter you are in debug or release mode (which is expected too)." your expectations are off. Code with undefined behavior can produce any output, you should not expect anything

Comment: @RichardCritten Well I was expecting same value to be produced in debug and release mode.

Comment: UB means anything can happen including the compiler [making nasal daemon flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) or formatting your hard drive

Comment: With gcc 11.1 -O3 I get 0 for your last test case: https://godbolt.org/z/EqhTzP4TE. (not that it means anything, because undefined behavior can produce any output ;)

Comment: When you have Undefined Behaviour (you do) the compiler and program have no concept of expected behaviour at all. All you can do is it fix the UB and try again, eg [Old New Thing - Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)