# Does assigning infinite values to integer types have undefined behavior?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

The C Standard specifies how finite floating point values are converted upon storing them into integer types, but it does not seem to specify the behavior for non finite values:

> **6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**
>
> 1    When a finite value of standard floating type is converted to an integer type other than `bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.
>
> 2    When a finite value of decimal floating type is converted to an integer type other than `bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the "invalid" floating-point exception shall be raised and the result of the conversion is unspecified.
>
> 3    When a value of integer type is converted to a standard floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined. Results of some implicit conversions may be represented in greater range and precision than that required by the new type (see 6.3.1.8 and 6.8.6.4).
>
> 4    When a value of integer type is converted to a decimal floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted cannot be represented exactly, the result shall be correctly rounded with exceptions raised as specified in IEC 60559.

Is the behavior specified or undefined elsewhere in the C Standard?

Comment: Corresponding C++ question: [Is casting of infinity to integer undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38795544/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270: yes, this question is C++ specific and the accepted answer refers to the C specification of the `trunc` function, an a stretched interpretation of 4.10.  The current language of the C Standard is more precise and only pertains to *finite values*.

Answer (score 7):

Converting infinite values of floating types to integer types is undefined C, not because of what the standard *says*, but because of what it *does not say*.

> Is the behavior undefined elsewhere in the C Standard?

The standard does not need to explicitly declare behavior as "undefined" for it to be undefined. It is enough to simply not define it.  This is very the definition of what *undefined behavior* is. Quoting [N3096/3.4.3](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf),

> 3.4.3
> **undefined behavior** 
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this document imposes no requirements

<sup>Note: as mentioned in [Eric Postpischil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77384525/11082165), the standard also states there there is no difference between behavior explicitly lablled "undefined" and behavior for which any definition is omitted. Both are equally undefined behavior.</sup>

The standard only imposes requirements on the conversion of *finite* values of floating types to integer types. Every case not covered by standard is, ipso facto, undefined behavior.

For extra reassurance, there is the following entry under Annex J.2 (Undefined Behavior):

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
> ...
> (16) Conversion to or from an integer type produces a value outside the range that can be represented (6.3.1.4).

Since infinity is indeed outside the range that an integer type can represent, converting infinity to an integer type is undefined.

Comment: Really?  How does `int x = INF;` fit the language of `3.4.3`? there is no erroneous data involved.  What you describe seems to correspond to *unspecified behavior*.

Comment: The *conversion* of a non-finite value is not specified in 6.3.1.4, hence you cannot say that it **is** infinity and hence outside the range of the integer type.  The phrase starts with *When a finite value*, hence it does not apply to non-finite values.

Comment: You are reasoning with common sense, and I agree with your conclusion, but I am expecting a formal proof in the language of the Standard.

Comment: Interestingly, the language used in C89 was *When a value of floating type is converted to integral type. the fractional part is discarded. If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integral type. the behavior is undefined.*  So your reasoning about infinities did somewhat apply then, but not for `NaN` values.

Comment: @chqrlie I do not follow why you think this does not fit the language of 3.4.3. Consider a different example: is `a / b` defined for integers `a` and `b`? Of course, it depends on what `b` is --- for some values, the standard imposes requirements on how the program will behave (i.e. it will compute the quotient of `a` divided by `b`), but for a certain value of `b` (`0`), the standard does not define the behavior. That's a "use of erroneous data". The story here isn't any different. For some values. the standard defines the behavior of `int x = <floating type>`. For others, it does not.

Comment: What I have described is not unspecified behavior. Unspecified behavior is when the standard _does_ state how the program will behave, but provides different alternatives that implementations can select between. Literally (3.4.4): "behavior upon which this document provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance".

Comment: OK, I'll buy that.  So the answer is pertinent for the first part.  The *extra reassurance* is not needed and does not apply because the conversion of an infinite value is not defined.

Comment: @chqrlie: When the Standard was written, some floating-point implementations trapped on attempts to convert out-of-range values.  In order to allow floating-point-to-integer conversions to be interleaved with other unrelated operations without recognizing a distinction between implementations where such conversions might trap and those where they never would, it was necessary for the Standard to *waive jurisdiction* over the effect of all such conversions, on the presumption that implementations which process such conversions in whatever way would be most useful for their programmer customers.

Comment: @chqrlie: Many people abuse the Standard to claim that it forbids constructs over which it *waives jurisdiction*, when such waiver of jurisdiction means the authors fo the Standard made no effort to consider what corner cases should be processed usefully by implementations claiming to be suitable for various purposes.

Comment: @supercat: this sounds like first hand experience... I remember those days too. I am just surprised at the silence of the Standard about this.  I guess leaving the behavior not explicitly undefined allows for various implementations to have their own documented behaviors for architectures where it matters.

Comment: @chqrlie: The published Rationale states that characterizing actions as UB, among other things, allows implementations to extend the semantics of the language by specifying how they will behave in situations where the Standard waives jurisdiction.  The authors recognized that many constructs would be processed in *usefully different* ways by different implementations, and did not want to disturb the status quo.  The notion that they wanted to forbid all such actions directly contradicts what the authors of the Standard wrote in both the Charter and Rationale documents.

Comment: @supercat: then I guess it would not hurt to specify the conversion of non-finite values to integer types as *undefined behavior* for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @chqrlie: Contrary to myth, the Standard explicltly states that there is no difference in emphasis between specifying that an action invokes UB, neglecting to specify its behavior at all, or specifying a constraint which the action does not abide.  If there's nothing that could be interpreted as specifying a behavior, there's no need to explicitly say that an action invokes UB.

Answer (score 5):

C 2018 4 2 says:

> If a “shall” or “shall not” requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. **Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this document** by the words "undefined behavior" or **by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior.** There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe “behavior that is undefined”.

Since there is no explicit definition of the behavior of converting an infinite value to an integer type, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C17 6.3.1.4 §1 kind of addresses it, since it speaks explicitly about finite floating values being valid conversions, implying that infinite ones are not:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

I believe one might also say that this is covered by the "catch all" rule which is also the one handling signed integer overflow, C17 6.5 §5:

> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not
> mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is
> undefined.